# How do you handle a UIPickerView in UI Automation iPhone application testing?

Tags: javascript, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios-ui-automation

In the following UI Automation script code, I'm able to get the values from a UIPickerView, but I'm not able to select the picker:

```
var picker = window.pickers(); 

UIALogger.logMessage("picker array count: " + picker.length);

var pickerWheels = picker[0].wheels();

UIALogger.logMessage("picker Wheel count: " + pickerWheels.length);

var pickerWheelsValues =pickerWheels[0].values();

UIALogger.logMessage("picker Values count: " + pickerWheelsValues);

pickerWheels[0].values()[0].tap();
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the [apple dev forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/242678) message 242678.

essentially you have to:

```
pickerWheel.tapWithOptions({x:hitPointX, y:hitPointY}, {touchCount:1, tapCount:1});
```

The trick is that the hitPoint has to be in the next or previous row.

Answer (score 1):

This is beautiful javascript implementation of pickerWheel automation
https://devforums.apple.com/message/242678

Answer (score 0):

You should use .selectValue() method.

```
var value = pickerWheels[0].values()[0]; // or any other valid value
pickerWheels[0].selectValue(value);
```

I found that in some situations selectValue throws "An exception occurred while trying to run the script." This happens when target is not correctly set- log element tree and check if UAITarget name is not empty (in case of simulator it should be "iPhone Simulator"). See Edit Active Target under target selection and make sure that under Options correct Simulator version (you have compiled for) is set.

Answer (score 0):

**For XCUIAutomation (iOS 10+)**

```
app.pickers
    .children(matching: .pickerWheel)
    .element
    .adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "My Value")
```